# Pycharm 2017.1 Open Debug Command Line is not working at all

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I was not sure if anyone else has run into this issue, but in the new Pycharm 2017.1 the Open Debug Command Line option is not working at all. I created a test case and ran it with `py.test` with no problem. But when I have a breakpoint and try to `Open Debug Command Line` the debug console only opens a regular python console with no connection to the underlying debug process. I can't seem to access any variables in the debug scope either.

I have posted an issue to the Jetbrains Pycharm issue [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23401) issue PY-23401.

In the image below you can see the debug console opened at the bottom of the screenshot. I tried to enter some variable values from the debug session, but don't receive an error and don't receive any info either. Has anyone else run into this, and has anyone found a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: When upgrading to community 2017 I had to remove all my breakpoints (from all projects) first to get debugging to work again. <CTRL><SHIFT><F8> to see all breakpoints, then click on the (-) to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to install Pycharm version 2017.1.2. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `lower_ml` variable is `None`.
Try going back into the debugger tab, and setting a watcher for it. Or try `lower_ml is None` in the console.

Comment: Hey @Batman thanks for the suggestion. I checked but the `lower_m1` variable does have a value. It should be a list containing two arrays. The other strange thing is that the debug command line usually open up an Ipython console--since I use Anaconda. For some reason in 2017.1 the console opens IDLE, which is wrong. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Weird then. Do you have the right Python executable set in your preferences?

Comment: Yep, I checked the project settings and all. The thing is that the project was working just fine in Pycharm 2016.3. So the debug command line was fine and all. I had not changed anything in the project. It was just the shift to 2017.1 and then everything stopped working. Seems like the issue is that somehow a pointer to the project configuration is off, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Also it's not possible anymore to run individual functions from tests. The 2017.1 release seems to be a bit broken.